# Data inserted into a form disappears on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, click

I'm trying to insert data through the following JavaScript code. The data inserted, however, disappears from the table when I click <kbd>Submit</kbd>.

Here's my code:

```js
let myform = document.querySelector("form");
let myFN = document.getElementById("fname");
let myLN = document.getElementById("lname");
let MyPar = document.querySelector("p");
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");

myform.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  if (myFN.value === "" || myLN.value === "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    MyPar.textContent = 'you need to fill all';
  }
});


myform.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  document.getElementById("table").style.display = "block";

  // trigger the table form page
  let table = document.getElementById("table");
  let row = table.insertRow(-1);
  let fname1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let lname1 = row.insertCell(1);


  fname1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  lname1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value;
});
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="fname">First name: </label>
    <input id="fname" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lname">Last name: </label>
    <input id="lname" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
<p></p>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You should always prevent default in submit handler, your website just refreshes

Answer (score 1):

First, you should remove the event listener that checks whether or not the input fields are blank. You instead can use `required` for the input tags in the HTML because it has a [built-in form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation).

Then, all you need to do is remove the if statement around the `e.preventDefault()` so it is executed every time the button is clicked.

```js
let myform = document.querySelector("form");
let myFN = document.getElementById("fname");
let myLN = document.getElementById("lname");
let MyPar = document.querySelector("p");
let submit = document.getElementById("submit");


myform.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});


myform.addEventListener("submit", function() {
  document.getElementById("table").style.display = "block";

  // trigger the table form page
  let table = document.getElementById("table");
  let row = table.insertRow(-1);
  let fname1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let lname1 = row.insertCell(1);


  fname1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  lname1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value;
});
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="fname">First name: </label>
    <input id="fname" type="text" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="lname">Last name: </label>
    <input id="lname" type="text" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>FirstName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your input to button change didn't do anything

Comment: @Konrad, can you clarify? The button no longer submits the form, there's form validation, and the table is being populated.

Comment: This is because you run `e.preventDefault()` every time, not because you used a button. Every button is of type `submit` by default

Comment: You can add own text to input using a `value` attribute